# Rewrite URL php to html with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Let’s say I have this URL:
http://example.com/search.php?key=abc&advance=xyz&page=1

And I want this URL:
http://example.com/search?key=abc&advance=xyz&page=1

OR
http://example.com/search.html?key=abc&advance=xyz&page=1

Please help me

Comment: Please provide what is your current rule which you've tried for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rewrite engine.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html [nc]
```